# Publishing From Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, publishing, visual-studio-express

I am an amateur programmer.  When I publish an app from Visual Studio Express, I have no option to make the package install for "All users of this computer".  Is this possible to do from Visual Studio Express?  If so then where is the option?  If not, do I need to use the full version of VS or do I need some other package authoring software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you got to have the VS professional version to get the full functionality of application deployment.